# I want static content cached, but browsers keep requesting it

Tags: http, iis-7.5, cache

I've got an IIS 7.5 site with caching turned on for javascript and css content directories.  All requests to these files use a query string with the app version number, so I just want it to cache forever.  But I can't get it to work

In IIS, I've get the caching set up, and I see that the responses for the css files come back with the HTTP Header "Cache-Control: max-age=31536000".

However, the browser keeps requesting the file as I browse pages.  The server is responding with 304 - Not Modified which is nice, but I want to avoid the round-trip entirely.

The browser REQUEST keeps including the header "Cache-Control: max-age=0".  I don't know if that's a helpful clue or not

Comment: Do you have `Etag` line in header response? You may want to get rid of it as it is the one that most likely forces browser to send those "If not modified" requests (although I do have them enabled myself and I see browser asking for such file once in a while (usually only after initial request) but not constantly for sure). BTW -- how do you check the headers (that file is cached) -- I hope not by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser? If you can -- can you post a link to such site/file?

Comment: Check your expires header - if it is set and contains any error that value will over-ride your max-age. You may also want to add 'public' to your Cache-control line

Comment: I'm checking the caching just by browsing the site and watching in fiddler or Chrome's network tab.  The server is not sending a Expires header, but it is sending an ETag header.  I'll try removing that.

Comment: @Clyde This is the header that I have: `Cache-Control: max-age=31622400,public` ; I do have `Etag` and I do not have `Expires` header .. but I still have all of my static resources cached (lucky me?). Please also do what @cyberx86 suggested: add to web.config: `<system.webServer><httpProtocol><customHeaders><add name="Cache-Control" value="public" /></customHeaders></httpProtocol></system.webServer>`

Comment: OK, I got the answer -- it's a developer issue not an IIS issue so my whole question is a bit of a red herring.  There are some javascript location.reload(true) in the code which are forcing re-requests of the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048740/stop-browser-to-make-http-requests-for-images-that-should-stay-cached-mod-expi/10176965#10176965

Answer (score 3):

I thought about deleting the question, but then decided to put my resolution out here in case it might be helpful to someone.  To copy from my comment:  it's a developer issue not an IIS issue so my whole question is a bit of a red herring. There are some javascript location.reload(true) in the code which are forcing re-requests of the data.

Comment: That's a good decision -- never knows where the trouble may be.